# Compare files with master repo using git eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I need to replace my local file with my master. I am using eclipse git plugin.

So i right click the file using compare with and i click index with head, it says file is not staged. What is this staged and how can i make it staged now?

My second question is, suppose i want to directly compare a file with the origin repo not my master repo. Can i do this using eclipse git plugin? If not how can i achive it may be with git bash?

Comment: Read Egit user guide from here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide everything is explained with screenshots